# How can I close other apps with root?

Tags: android, rooted-device

My app runs on rooted devices. I need to close another app when my app runs. How can I do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Run `am force-stop com.other.app.package` in a shell. I'm  not even convinced you have to have root for that to work.